# Dog vs dawg pronunciation

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

What is the difference in pronunciation between **[dog](https://www.google.com/search?q=dog%20definition&oq=dog%20defi&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l6j69i60.4866j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** and the slang **[dawg](https://www.google.com/search?q=dawg++slang+definition&sxsrf=ALeKk02tNSFla07x_Hx3KAM1FxPS6m9kWQ%3A1622636876485&ei=THm3YIyIHcGoa87Pv_gD&oq=dawg++slang+definition&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyAggAOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgcIIxCwAhAnOgYIABAHEB46CAgAEAgQBxAeOgYIABANEB46CAgAEA0QBRAeOgQIABANOggIABAIEA0QHjoECCMQJzoICAAQBxAKEB46BQgAEMsBOgQIABAeUPW1AViexQFgsMYBaAJwAngAgAGPAYgB4AmSAQQxLjEwmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiM3vy0-fjwAhVB1BoKHc7nDz8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5)** ?

Can  the context make the difference ?

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary? What did that tell you? Do you have any examples of the contexts in which you suspect they differ?

Comment: It is called [eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect). 'Dog' is not usually *spelled* 'dawg' but in some regions, it is pronounced that way. Although [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dawg) has **dawg** informal US, non-standard spelling of dog.

Comment: The vowel sound in "dog" is "longer" than the sound in "dawg".

Comment: @HotLicks Only in American English. In British English that's not the case.

Comment: In British English it is in fact the opposite.

Comment: @HotLicks: the spelling *dawg* is commonly used today to denote either the AAVE or the NYC pronunciation of *dog* with a diphthong, both of which are longer than the usual vowel in *dog*.

Comment: Oy veh, *dawg* is above all southern American English.

Comment: In California, *dawg* means something like *homie* or *dude*, and, as @HotLicks says, the vowel sound is drawn out. *What up, dawwwwg?* It sounds just like *dog*, but elongated.

Comment: @Cascabel - By "long" I mean the meaning of the term when I was taught it, 60 years ago.

Comment: @Cascabel  By "long o" he means the "tense" or "close" /o/ of *coat, core, comb, no, foe, low* not the "open" or "lax" /ɔ/ of *all, wall, ball, log, dog, frog, lawn, wrong, thought*, which he would call "short o".

Answer (score 5):

TLDR: I believe this depends on when the text you're reading was written. It likely indicates an alternate pronunciation, but which alternate pronunciation depends on context. If the text is fairly recent, it may indicate an African-American Vernacular English (AAVE) pronunciation of *dog* with a diphthong. If the text is American and was written between 1840 and 1940, it quite likely indicates a non-standard pronunciation that educated people generally didn't use then (although today it's one of the most accepted pronunciations). It might also indicate the usual pronunciation of *dog*. I don't know what *dawg* would indicate in British texts.

In the late 19th and early 20th century, the accepted pronunciation of *dog* among educated Americans was /dɑg/, with the vowel of *dock*, and /dɔɡ/, with the vowel of *dawn*, was a non-standard pronunciation.
You can see this because [dictionaries](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Webster_s_Primary_School_Dictionary/pJ0VAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dictionary+webster&pg=PP3&printsec=frontcover) from this period gave the pronunciation [dɑɡ].

Authors would use the spelling *dawg* to indicate that a speaker was uneducated or rural. This puzzled me as a child, because I pronounced the word [dɔɡ] and I couldn't figure out what pronunciation the spelling *dawg* represented.

Today, half of Americans have the COT-CAUGHT merger, and can't tell the difference between the pronunciations /dɑg/ and /dɔɡ/, and most of the rest of us use the formerly non-standard pronunciation /dɔɡ/, so to indicate this pronunciation you don't need an alternate spelling today ... it should be spelled *dog*.

From [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dawg+%2C+frawg&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdawg%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrawg%3B%2Cc0), I suspect the pronunciation /dɔɡ/ was non-standard roughly between the years 1840 and 1940, because this is where the spelling *dawg* is most common. There's also a more recent peak, since around 2000, which must indicate the AAVE pronunciation of *dawg*, which is something like [dɒʊɡ].

There's actually even another possibility.  New Yorkers [use a diphthong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_accent) for some words thata contain the phoneme /ɔ/, like *coffee* and *dog* — something like [kɔəfi] and [dɔəg] — and you sometimes see the spellings *cawffee* and *dawg* used to indicate this New York pronunciation.

Comment: Modern “dawg” is a very different word, with origins in AAVE. I have the COT-CAUGHT merger, but I pronounce “dawg” differently from “dog”. Sadly, I don’t know IPA well enough to explain how, but it’s a different dipthong than “coffee”.

Comment: @StephenS: You're right. Today *dawg* is often used for an AAVE/Southern pronunciation of *dog*, which I believe is a different diphthong than the one New Yorkers use. If I can figure out what the IPA for it is, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @PeterShor It's definitely different from the Long Island pronunciation, but for a lot of people with Cot/Caught Merger, using that as the example is the easiest way for them to understand the difference between 'dahg' and 'dawg.'

Comment: The "dawg" in NY and the "dawg" in the south ain't the same dog. Perhaps someone more adept at phonemes can transcribe  them for me.

Comment: @Lambie: I've transcribed them as [dɔəg] (NYC) and [dɒʊɡ] (South) in my answer. I'm fairly sure I've transcribed the NYC one correctly, since I use it in a few words like *dog*, *off*, *wrong*, and *Chicago* — a remnant of my living in NYC until I was 4 (although [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_accent) says it can also be [oə] or [ʊə]). I'm not that sure about the AAVE pronunciation.

Comment: The AAVE and southern one are more similar.  Thanks. Gosh, I truly would not have thought that "until 4" could impact an accent so much. :)

Comment: @Lambie: Nearly all of my NYC accent has gone, but even after 50 years, I still use that vowel in *off* (but not *cough*) and in *wrong* (but not *long*). I guess accents are funny.

Comment: When living in NYC from '87 to '01, I strove mightily to avoid it but was sometimes caught [ɔəg: ha ha] off guard. However, in writing, I still cross my sevens (raised in Brazil). Cheers.